# How can I commit a single file using SVN over a network?

Tags: svn, ubuntu, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am able to check out an entire `svn` repository using the following command:

```
svn co https://myaccount.svn.beanstalkapp.com/myapp/
```

But I cannot figure out the command to commit a single file. If I make to change to `myapp/page1.html`.

How can I check in just that one file?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
cd myapp/trunk
svn commit -m "commit message" page1.html
```

For more information, see:

```
svn commit --help
```

I also recommend [this free book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), if you're just getting started with Subversion.

Answer (score 9):

1. `svn add filename.html`
2. `svn commit -m"your comment"`
3. You dont have to push

Comment: Be careful here! This will not just `commit` the newly added file, but also the changes to all the previously added files on the `svn` index.

Answer (score 7):

You have a file myFile.txt you want to commit.

The right procedure is :

1. Move to the file folder
2. `svn up`
3. `svn commit myFile.txt -m "Insert here a commit message!!!"`

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 4):

strange that your command works, i thougth it would need a target directory. but it looks like it assumes current pwd as default.

```
cd myapp
svn ci page1.html
```

you can also just do `svn ci` in or on that folder and it will detect all changes automatically and give you a list of what will be checked in

`man svn` tells you the rest

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
cd /You folder name
svn commit 'your file path' -m "Commit message you want to give"
```

You can also drage you files to command promt instead to write cd [common in MAC OSx]

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
svn commit -m "<Your message here>" path/to/your/file
```

you can also add multiple files like this:

```
svn commit -m "<Your message here>" path/to/your/file [path/to/your/file] [path/to/your/file]
```