# how to commit single file in svn using ant

Tags: macos, file, svn, ant, commit

The file is already in svn, I do some changes to the file on macos and I want to commit it back to svn through my buildscript using ant.
 I know the process for a single file commit involves

1.add the specified file and

2.commit the specified file.

My doubt is can we add, again if the file is already existing in the file, because I did some changes and i want to commit only that file, and should not disturb the other files in the directory.

How can we do this on mac like operating system? what's the process?

Answer (score 0):

As [noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037033/how-can-i-commit-a-single-file-using-svn-over-a-network), you can commit just one file.  You can use the Ant exec command to be able to run that svn command line through ant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this target to commit a single file in svn

```
<svnSetting
      svnkit="true"
      username="bingo"
      password="bongo"
      id="svn.settings"
  />
<svn refid="svn.settings">
    <commit file="your.file" />
</svn>
```